# How to handle logout in spring application

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

I have spring app on which the logout is not implemented properly. when i click on my menu option  it opens new windows for "ABC" application. so when i clicks on log-out it log-out from whole application, my intention is to log out from "ABC" application not from whole application. Please advice how should implement this log-out functionality.
Is it possible to create new session on menu option and when i clicks on log out then it remove newly created session?

Answer (score 1):

In a simple scheme, all you need to do is arrange that your application logout button sends the browser to  `<context-path>/j_spring_security_logout`, where `<context-path>` is your webapp's context path.

You also need a `<logout>` element in your `<http>` element to tell SpringSecurity to configure the logout filter.

Comment: could you please provides more detail about this. on log out i have write down following line  <a id="logout" href="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_logout' />">Logout</a>